# Nodes in circular list having the same value

Tags: c, circular-list

I have the following code:(courtesy to Armin )

```
 int InsForward (TL2 p, void* x){
 /* Inserta a node a step forward from the supplied p*/
 TL2 h = (TL2)calloc(1,sizeof(TCel2));
 if (!h)
    return 0;
h->pre = p;        //sets h previous to point to p
h->nxt= p->nxt;    //sets h next to point to where p was pointing ( sentinel )
p->nxt->prv = h;   //sets the sentinel previous to point to h
p->nxt = h;        //sets the p next to point to h
h->info = x;   
return 1;
```

What I tried:

```
/* TCel a, int p, FILE fi*/
while(fscanf(fi,"%i%i", &(p.x), &(p.y)) == 2)
 if ( InsForward(a, &p) == 0)   
   break;
```

The struct:

```
typedef struct cel2
{ 
  struct cel2 *pre, *nxt;  
 void* info;              
} TCel2, *TL2;
```

So I checked it:

```
 /* TL2 u*/

 for (u = a->nxt; u != a; u = u->nxt)
   printf("%p \n",  u->info);
```

Yes, the info is void, but I was curious if the addresses were different...I suppose no:

```
 0028FEA8 0028FEA8 0028FEA8 0028FEA8 0028FEA8 0028FEA8
```

Why are they the same?!

Comment: You are printing `u->info` twice. Why do you think they should be different?

Comment: The loop ends, I have read 7 elements. It doesn't matter if I print u twice, the output is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop, you are never creating a new `p`. You are reusing the same `p` to store the results of `fscanf`, and then using a pointer to `p` to set the `info` field of your nodes.

```
while(fscanf(fi,"%i%i", &(p.x), &(p.y)) == 2)
 if ( InsForward(a, &p) == 0)   
   break;
```

That's why all the pointers end up pointing to that same `p`. This would not be what you want, because:

1. All your nodes will be pointing to the same `p` as their `info`.
2. Since you are creating a dynamic # of these nodes, you should allocate these info structs on the heap with `malloc`, `calloc`, etc.

I assume `p` is a struct with an `x` and `y` field, both of which are `int`s. You should so something like this instead. I'll call this struct `tuple_t`.

```
while(true) {
 tuple_t *p = malloc(sizeof(tuple_t));
 int f = fscanf(fi,"%i%i", &(p->x), &(p->y));
 if (f != 2 || InsForward(a, p) == 0) {
   break;
}
```

Of course, you'll need to add more error handling and memory management as you see fit.